# Which is best method to calculate Sperling’s Ride Index?

Tags: dft

I am trying to make a prtotype for measuring Comfort/Ride Index of a testing track road using Sperling’s Ride Index. I looked into a lot of research papers done on this but unable to find the best way to calculate it.

I am using Cortex M4 based controller and using ADC at 100Hz sampling from an accelerometer connected at base of a vehicle. I run CMSIS DFT function with 1024 samples (values converted to g before feeding to FFT algo function) at a time and gather output in frequency domain. As per my knowledge, the output is array consisting both of real and imaginary parts and I need to RMS the both to get magnitude. But after this I am stuck.

Sperling’s Ride Index equation says
$$
RI = 0.896 * \sqrt[10]{\frac{\sum_{1}^{n} (\frac{b^{3} * G(f)}{f}))}{n}}
$$
b being peak acceleration for each frequency f across n samples considered for RI Calculation.

Now my RMS values are not g values (I mean amplitude of spectrum). So how do I get the actual amplitude at a particular frequency?
And also I am not sure which frequency values I need to consider for summing in the equation.

Edit:

As per my knowledge,

'g' is acceleration due to gravity, This is measurmeent I get from accelerometer.

In a car ride, We shall sample vertical acceleration over a period of time (say 20sec) at a sampling rate 100Hz. Then we want to find out all frequency of vibrations we got (These frequencies will be between 0-50Hz) using FFT on those samples

(You can imagine an audio wave having mixed frequncy signals between 0-50Hz is sampled at 100Hz and I am trying to find which frequency component of audio wave had amplitudes greater than a fixed Threshold)

Sperling's Ride Index equation results in a number that represents how comfortable the ride on the car was over the 20sec ride. Summation is required to be done on all those frequencies that had amplitude of 'g' greater than fixed threshold( example threshhold of 0.2g - i.e. the change in g while riding was > 0.2)

Comment: Sorry I don't know about the Sperling's Ride, the equation is not clear to me what is $f$, what is $g$, what do you mean by acceleration of a frequency? if be is for each frequency shouldn't it be $b(f)$ ? the summation is in $f$, or is a summation in $k$ and the terms are in $f_k$, if that's the case how is $f_k$ defined?

Comment: @Bob: Thanks for reply. I could not fit answers in comment box. I have updated the main question with answers to your query.
You can assume G(f) is just a Constant real Number